# Meteor how to load script dynamically?

Tags: meteor

Is this possible to load script dynamically? for eg. I wish to reduce app weight. so I would like to load role based JS. I know its not best solution to reduce app weight but looking for interesting package or approach

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no native support for dynamic/lazy loading in Meteor. There is an open request for it though:

https://github.com/MeteorCommunity/discussions/issues/27

And it is on their roadmap:

https://trello.com/c/24s6vyxo/55-incremental-loading

In the meantime there is a package that does help/address this via bundles:

https://github.com/numtel/meteor-lazy-bundles